# xcode copy dylib into bundle with lazy loading

Tags: c++, c, xcode, lazy-loading, dylib

I have an application (cocoa app) which loads a dylib (c library) lazy (dlopen).
This dylib (the xcode project incl. sourcecode) is also a part of the workspace in xcode.
Now I want xcode to automatically copy the dylib into the app bundle when the app is built (also compile it if necessary), but the app executable should not depend on it. (otool -L shouldn't show it)

Is this possible without doing it manually?
I can't change the app to link to the dylib by the way.

Also: is it normal for a dylib on osx to depend on itself when calling "otool -L x.dylib"? Mine does so and some of the system libs also seem to do this. On linux when I use ldd this isn't the case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by making the dylib project a subproject (just drag and drop it) of the cocoa app. Then you can add a copy on bundling target.